# Used heap not shrinking after a doGet request has been processed

Tags: servlets, heap-memory

I have a java client that whenever a user click on a button calls a servlet on the server (get request). The server gets some data from a database, generates a file and sends a boolean back to the client saying if the file has been successfully created on not. 
The problem I am facing is that every time the user clicks on the button (client side) the server heap is increased by about 50MB and when the doGet request has been successfully handled it never shrinks back to the size it had before the request. 
Am I missing something? Am I supposed to close the connection from the client somehow? How can I convince the server to deallocate the objects he created while handling the doGet request?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: It was a continuous profiling, calling the garbage collector does not seem to make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly freeing you memory resource in finalize block ?
Wisely using finally and finalize can help you free extra resources/memory space. Please do let copy your code here to have some suggestions for memory.
This will help in rectifying whether you are not using  PermGen space instead of HeapSpace memory unnecessarily. for example it makes difference if you use 
String str1= "foo"; and Vs String str2 = new ("foo");

Where str1 is not garbage collectible being a part of PermGen while other str2 is in heap memory space.

Comment: Since I am only creating variables inside the doGet method, shouldn't all these variables (regardless if they belong in the heap or the PermGen) be cleared after the method returns?

Comment: @Rossella No ways... as java never guarantees the garbage collection neither can you enforce it explicitly. So in my opinion finalize can be good call for it.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example of how to use finalize and what to put in it?